# Postfix not changing port 25 to 587

Tags: smtp, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, postfix-mta

I use digital-ocean hosting and ubuntu 16.04,
I install postfix and use smtp to send outgoing mail,
This is step i do :
1. Change Firewall Setting

```
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
```

use telnet and it connected

2. My **main.cf **:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = domain_name.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, domain_name.com, droplet_name, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

3. My master.cf :

```
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_enforce_tls = yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

4. restart my postfix
5. Echo mail in console, mail not sent, this is the log :

```
Jan 18 03:19:21 droplet-name postfix/smtp[25134]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.194.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 18 03:19:51 droplet-name postfix/smtp[25134]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.202.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 18 03:20:21 droplet-name postfix/smtp[25134]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.10.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 18 03:20:51 droplet-name postfix/smtp[25134]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.145.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 18 03:21:21 droplet-name postfix/smtp[25134]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.253.112.27]:25: Connection timed out
```

I have tried configured it for 2 days and still no mail through

Note : I already tried with [smtp.gmail.com]:587 as relay, and it sent mail, but i want use mydomain as outgoing only, without third party

Thank's in advanced

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server hosting provider blocked port 25, please contact them to open it or use another server on different hosting company and ensure port 25 is open before installing mail server. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean blocks port 25 on outgoing traffic by default. If you contact customer support, the standard reply is ---

"You are unable to send mail as outgoing SMTP traffic is blocked at this time. After 60 days have passed you can request that the SMTP block on your account be lifted at that time.

Please let us know if you have any other questions!”

Meaning you can request for the block to be lifted, and after 60 days (where they presumably moniter your account for spam-like activity) they will open port 25 for outgoing traffic.